# Word letterhead generating macro does not apply formatting consistently

Tags: vba, ms-word, text-formatting

I'm using Microsoft Word 2010, and every macro I try and create for a letterhead does not work. The formatting of my text is not shown when I run the macro! The size changes, but the bold does not apply. The weird thing is every time I run the macro in the same document or in a different document, it doesn't ever show the same.

I'd like a letterhead macro to turn out like this (The top line should be in 16, the second line in 10 and the last two lines in size 12):

> Turner and Sons Accouting Pty Ltd
>
> ABN: 22 333 111 555
>
> 22 Kings St, Sydney 2000
>
> Phone: (02) 9675 4444 Fax: (02) 9675 4443

The code for the text is:

```
Sub Letterhead()
'

' Letterhead Macro
'

'
Selection.TypeText Text:="Turner and Sons Accounting Pty Ltd"
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
Selection.Font.Size = 10
Selection.TypeText Text:="ABN: 22 333 111 555"
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.Font.Size = 12
Selection.TypeText Text:="22 Kings St, Sydney 2000"
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeText Text:="Phone: (02) 9675 4444 Fax: (02) 9675 4443"
End Sub
```

Comment: Rather than use a macro to create a letterhead, you should be using a template. http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/LetterheadRibbon.htm You are doing things the hard way. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm The formatting should be done using ***styles*** in your template, not direct formatting. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/stylesImportance.htm

Answer (score 0):

Is it just the "bold" that is inconsistant, if so this is due to your  "Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle" line, change this instead to "Selection.Font.Bold = True"

You can then add "Selection.Font.Bold = False" to the end so you resume in standard font..

Adam